# Sort array contains numeric string using c# array

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting

Please refer the following array,

`string[] numArray = {"two","three","one", "seven","nine", "two", "one"};`

we need sort this array by numeric and return the sorted array like

```
string[] output = {"one","one","two","two","three","seven","nine"};
```

Please suggest the best logic in c# code using only string array or any method.

Comment: It seems homework to me.

Comment: translate the number names to numeric values, and sort by the numeric values.

Comment: what have _you_ tried, where is _your_ code?

Comment: @styx don't have a code

Comment: @SENTHILVEL SO is not a "Code writing service".

Comment: We won't write code for you, as StackOverflow isn't a code writing service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need give an order (actually a [equivalence relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation)) to be able to sort. The order on characters is usually a,b,c,... and the order usually given on words such as 'one' is called [lexicographic order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order). However you want to sort by the meaning behind, its **semantic**: integers.

Your computer doesn't know that you want this, so you need to provide the meaning., which is through a function (technically a dictionary).

Computers have order on integers builtin (it's also builtin in standard integers, in usual mathematics). Hence you need to provide a one-to-one function (eg., with a dictionary, or a list of uples eg., List<(string, int)>), so you sort your words from their integer peer. You can also map words with letters: one-a, two-b, ... and when you reach z, you continue with aa (it's a base 27 counting). You can also do this with bits (base 2), base64, etc. But there is always a map with integers.

IMHO, understanding is more important than knowing. Now you can code many solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You can store numbers in a dictionary where the keys would be strings (e.g. `"two"`) and the values would be integers (e.g. `2`). And by using LINQ you could first replace the strings in your input array with numbers and then sort them with `OrderBy`. After the numbers are sorted you can convert the numbers back to strings:

```
Dictionary<string, int> numbers = new Dictionary<string, int>() {
    { "one", 1 },
    { "two", 2 },
    { "three", 3 },
    { "four", 4 },
    { "five", 5 },
    { "six", 6 },
    { "seven", 7 },
    { "eight", 8 },
    { "nine", 9 },
};

string[] wordArray = { "two", "three", "one", "seven", "nine", "two", "one" };

var numberArray = Enumerable.Range(0, wordArray.Length)
                            .Select(i => numbers[wordArray[i]])
                            .OrderBy(x => x).ToArray();

var output = Enumerable.Range(0, numberArray.Length)
                       .Select(i => numbers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value == numberArray[i]).Key)
                       .ToArray();
```

`Output` = `{"one","one","two","two","three","seven","nine"}`